# How to fix "variable length differ" problem in export_summs() in R?

Tags: r

I want to generate regression output table using `huxtable` package as follows.

```
library(wooldridge)
library(jtools)
library(huxtable)
data('card')
str(card)

fit1 <- lm(card$educ~card$nearc4)
fit2 <- lm(card$educ~card$nearc4 + card$motheduc + card$fatheduc)
fit3 <- lm(card$lwage~card$nearc4)


if (requireNamespace("huxtable")) {
  # Export all 3 regressions with "Model #" labels,
  # standardized coefficients, and robust standard errors
  export_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3,
               model.names = c("Model 1","Model 2","Model 3"),
               scale = TRUE, robust = TRUE)
}
```

But I get the following error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = card$educ ~ `card$nearc4` +
> `card$motheduc` +  :    variable lengths differ (found for
> 'card$nearc4')

How can I display all three models in a single output table so that I may compare the three results?

Comment: Try `lm(educ ~ nearc4, data = card)`

Comment: @akrun, thanks, it's working. If you don't mind, could you briefly tell me why the previous one doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps you have NA values. The formula interface will automatically delete the relevant rows, if you use the data argument.